# Excel to Datatable gives error "Too many fields"

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel-2003

I am filling data from a sheet of Excel book to datatable . The excel sheet contains about 160 columns. It gives error message "to many fields"

```
 Dim largespan1 As String

Dim larg As String

Dim str, str5, str6 As String

largespan1 = "C:\shivam.xls"

Dim sConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & largespan1 & ";Extended                 Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=yes;IMEX=1"""

Dim len, len1, i As Integer

Dim cmd, cmd1 As New SqlCommand()

Dim objConn1 As New OleDbConnection(sConnectionString)

Dim objCmdSelect1 As New OleDbCommand("SELECT  * FROM  [Master Schedule1$]", objConn1)

objConn1.Open()

Dim objAdapter2 As New OleDbDataAdapter()

objAdapter2.SelectCommand = objCmdSelect1

Dim dt5 As New DataTable

objAdapter2.Fill(dt5)

objConn1.Close()
```

Any one can suggest why it happens
Thanks in advance